# Locally connected layer filters

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a problem understanding how the filters are used in Locally connected layer.
For example, say input is `6x6x3` image and we use one Conv2D(same padding) and one `LocallyConnected2D` with 4 filters each of size `3x3`.

```
filters, biases = model.layers[2].get_weights()
```

When I use `layer.get_weights()` on `conv2D`, it returns filters with shape `(3,3,3,4)` and bias shape `(4, )` which is expected as we have 4 filters with shape `3x3x3`.

But `layer.get_weights()` on `LocallyConnected2D` returns filters with shape `(16,36,4)` and bias shape `(4,4,4)`.

Why is the filter shape `16x36`?

I know that locally connected layer uses different filters at each input patch. How do we slide across the whole image with only 4 filters?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/local/) there is the warning for a layer with input `32x32x3` and `64 filters`:

> notice that this layer will consume (30*30)*(3*3*3*64) + (30*30)*64 parameters

Or:

- Kernel: `(patches x patches) * (size * size * input_channels * output_channels)`
- Bias: `(patches x patches) * output_channels`

Translating to your case:

> this layer will consume (4*4)*(3*3*4*4) kernel params + (4*4)*4 bias params.

Explanation:

- Your kernel size is `3x3` (first part of the second parentheses)
- Your input channels are 4 (third number in second parentheses) and output are 4 (fourth number)
- For images `6x6` and this kernel size, there are `4x4` patches. (Just as images `32x32` will have `30x30` patches for kernel size `3x3` without padding)

For the biases, `4x4` patches and `4` output channels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the output shapes. But how are 4 filters enough for 4x4=16 neurons in the output? As this being a Locally-connected layer, every output neuron must have a different filter (16 filters for 16 neurons). But I gave only 4 filters. So how are these 4 filters shared among all 16 output neurons?

Comment: You have `16` * 36 * 4 parameters for kernels and `16`*4 parameters for biases. So, what is missing?

Comment: I don't know if i'm missing something here. The parameters are there and rightly allocated to each output neuron. But I used 4 3x3 filters with depth 4 (3x3x4). So, we have 4x(3x3x4) = 144 weights. So, how come there are 16x36x4 = 2304 weights. How did keras implement these extra weights?

Comment: It's not extra, it's "locally connected". Its a filter per patch in the image. there are 4x4 patches. 4x4x144 = 2304

Comment: So if its a filter per patch in the image, there are 4x4=16 patches. Each patch needs a separate filter and not the same one used in the previous patch. So, my questions are: 1) shouldn't we need 16 filters? I used only 4 filters here.    2) And each filter can carry 3x3x4 = 36 weights, so 36x4 = 144 weights. Is this correct?

Comment: You *have* 16 filters already. That's why there are 16 x 144 parameters. You chose to have 4 filters "per patch". Everything is totally explained in the answer, which is not about output shapes at all.

Comment: Actually, the paper says something different. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.0448.pdf In section 2.1